# Gupta 3.0.0 | 166: Cannot create a front-end result set | Oracle

Tags: oracle, windows-7, guptateamdeveloper

Using Windows-7 Desctop, Oracle 12 and old Gupta 3.0.0-PTF1 sometime I get this silly SQL error message.

This is a longtime running programm and there is no syntax error. One or two time a day I get this. Error 166 is not really a ORACLE SQL-Error. So far as I know it comes from Gupta ORA SQL-Router DLL.

> 166: Cannot create a front-end result set

SQL Query looks like this. But this is not the only one and not the problem.

```
If SqlConnect( lvhs )
    If SqlPrepareAndExecute( lvhs, 'select 1 into :lvZahl from dual' )
        If SqlFetchNext( lvhs, lvInd )
```

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Update you question and a dd the related  code  ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Try Deleting all files that are accumulated in the Temp folder (router caches rows in temp file).

2.Verify that there is sufficient memory available.

3.Make sure your app have enough rights to access temp folder.... ie.OS security or non-admin issues.

4.You can disable the *front- end result set* by calling the function bOk = *SqlSetResultSet ( hSql, False )* in case result set is not required.

5.If you have multiple applications running simultaneously then you can assign individual TEMP-directories for each application by calling function *[SetEnvironmentVariableA()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686206(v=vs.85).aspx)*.

Comment: Thanks Point 1 and 2 not are not the reason. temp is empty not and every client has 8 GB RAM. The "...cannot error..." is still one or two time a day, so 3 cannot the reason. But 4 and 5 are possible. I will check this and come back later.

Comment: After one week test I can say, point 4 SqlSetResultSet ( hSql, False ) was my solution for this problem. Some hints from me:
If Gupta-Application have a lot of Sql Handle in class variables, I get often this "166: Cannot create a front-end result set" error. If Gupta-Application just have one or two global Sql Handle I get very less 166: Errors. So at last. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In this very old version of Gupta TeamDeveloper ( we're upto v7.1 now ) , Front-End result sets were held in the Temp folder - but often were not deleted. So they build up in there over time until there is literally no room for the next one.
You could write a class to go through and delete old ones, when the app shuts down, or a new connection is made, so new connections have room to create a new .frs file.  Better still upgrade your app to TeamDeveloper v7.0 and you wont go wrong !

Comment: @ GuptaSteve. Thanks for your comment, but we will not update to a newer version. We try to rewrite all to WebApplication.